# android AOSP compile external source

Tags: android, compilation, android-source

I tried to compile a github project with aosp so
I put the code into android_7.1_r36/external/githubProject
then I runned mm in order to start compilation but
`ninja: error .... missing and no known rule to make it`

What is the best practice to compile external project that use aosp libraries.

[github project i want compile](https://github.com/gburca/BinderDemo)

Comment: please add the Android.mk of your 'githubProject'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make it reachable from another MK that you know is been called.

Try adding your MODULE in the MK of the device you are **lunch**ing.